# How to use Custom Action Date (Date Type) in WCM?

Tags: websphere-portal, wcm, lotus-wcm

My Question is very specific to Custom Actions in WCM. There is one option called Custom Action Date available in Date type dropdown box while creating a Custom Action. I just want to know what it is and how can it is related to this function

```
  public Date getExecuteDate(Document arg0) {
      // code goes here
    return SomeDate
}
```

which we get while implementing interface CustomWorkflowAction like below-

```
 public class MyCustomWorkFlowAction implements    CustomWorkflowAction { }
```

one can visit this link-http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Customize_WCM_Workflow_Notification_Email_Body 
to check the code for CustomWorkflowAction. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes all you need is just open javadoc

```
java.util.Date getExecuteDate(Document document)
```

Get the Date that this action should execute. This method is always called prior to running the execute method.

**Parameters:**

document - Target document. Custom code must not modify the document in this method.

**Returns:**

Execute date. If date is in the past, the action will be executed immediately. Use the CustomWorkflowAction.DATE_EXECUTE_NOW constant to execute immediately. If the date is in the future, the action will be scheduled for this date. The returned execute date must be the same when run on any server where the action is syndicated. If the execute date is different, the scheduled action will run at different times on different servers.

if you just want you action executed, use this

```
public Date getExecuteDate(Document document) {
    return DATE_EXECUTE_NOW;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Georgy... but one question, How this function is related to the Custom Action Date available in Date type dropdown box while creating a Custom Action ? How to use Custom Action Date option?

Comment: Take a look http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3JLV_8.0.0/wcm/wcm_dev_workflows_creating_action_custom_props.dita?cp=SS3JLV_8.0.0%2F6-14-1-13-2